# Matrix operations using parameters modified through moving horizon estimation

Tags: python, gekko

I've recently started trying out moving horizon estimation with GEKKO. My specified manipulated variables are used in a heat balance equation within my model, and I am having some issues with the matrix operations in the model.

Example code:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

#creating a sample array of input values
nt = 51
u_meas = np.zeros(nt)
u_meas[3:10] = 1.0
u_meas[10:20] = 2.0
u_meas[20:40] = 0.5
u_meas[40:] = 3.0

p = GEKKO(remote=False)
p.time = np.linspace(0,10,nt)

n = 1 #process model order

#designating u as my input, and that I'm going to be using these measurements to estimate my parameters with MHE
p.u = p.MV(value=u_meas)
p.u.FSTATUS=1

#parameters I'm looking to modulate
p.K = p.FV(value=1, lb = 1, ub = 3) #gain
p.tau = p.FV(value=5, lb = 1, ub = 10) #time constant

p.x = [p.Intermediate(p.u)]

#constants within the model that do not change
X_O2 = 0.5
X_SiO2 = 0.25
X_N2 = 0.1
m_feed = 100

#creating an array with my feed separated into components. This creates a 1D array with the individual feed streams of my components. 
mdot_F_i = (np.tile(m_feed,3)*np.array([X_O2, X_SiO2, X_N2])

#at this point, I want to add my MV values to the end of my component feed array for later heat and mass balance equations. Normally, in my previous model without MHE, I would put

mdot_c_i = np.concatenate(mdot_F_i, x, (other MV variables after))
```

However, now that u is a specified MV in GEKKO, and not a set value, I get an error at the mdot_c_i line that says that the array at index 0 has 1 dimension, and the array at index 1 has 2 dimensions.

I'm guessing that I have to specify mdot_c_i as an intermediate variable within Gekko. I've tried a couple different variations, alternately specifying mdot_c_i as an intermediate and trying to use only the values of the MV; however, I keep getting that error.

Has anyone experiences similar issues to this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by using `np.append()` instead of `np.concatenate()`. Try something like:

```py
mdot_c_i = np.append(mdot_F_i, p.u)
```

Here is a minimum and complete example if you'd like to try it.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=-10,ub=10)
y = m.Var(5,lb=-5,ub=5)
z = np.append(x,y)
m.Minimize(np.dot([1,1,-1,1],z))
m.solve(disp=False)
print([zi.value[0] for zi in z])
# solution: [-10.0, -10.0, 10.0, -5.0]
```

Gekko variables need to be stored as objects, not as numerical values. The error may be because the `np.concatenate()` function is trying to access the length of the Gekko manipulated variable data `p.u.value` to concatenate those values instead of concatenating `p.u` as an object.